# How many boarding pass do i receive if my journey has 2 stops?

Tags: tickets, airlines

I am flying with QANTAS from Brisbane to New York, with a layover in Sydney and Los angeles.

- Brisbane to Sydney: QF559
- Flight from Sydney to LAX:QF11 Airbus380
- Flight from LAX to JFK: QF11 Boeing 747

How many boarding pass will I need to get?

Comment: Are you worried that you might somehow fail to get enough of them?

Comment: At checkin, the airline will issue you your boarding passes. You will get at least two (two different flight numbers), and possibly three (not sure about that QF11 with the same flight number but changing planes). In any case, the number of boarding passes is up to Qantas, and you don't need to know ahead of time how many you will get. You hold what you are issued, and show them when requested.

Comment: What is your concern?  When you check in, you will be issued with whatever Qantas deems necessary.  Given that your first stop in US is in LAX, you will be required to clear immigration and customs before boarding the LAX - JFK leg.  I would not be surprised if you are issued 3 boarding passes (one for each leg) so as not to confuse the simple TSA folk at LAX.

Comment: Why not ask Qantas?

Comment: @John If you have any real worries about whether you will manage to fly on this itinery, please state these concerns. Right now, your question seems to be one that was asked out of pure curiosity, such as "how many grains of rice are there in China?".

Answer (score 2):

You will get three.  While two flights carry the QF11 designator, they are different types of aircraft, so seat numbers can and mostly likely be different (unless you specifically pre-selected the exact same seat number).  As a result the system will automatically kick two boarding passes for everyone on QF11 going SYD-JFK.

Comment: While you are probably correct for this case, two distinct flights does not necessarily imply two boarding passes. I've had one boarding pass for two connecting flights (different flight numbers, different seats, different planes and everything) with SAS.